# My example with Tom Select does not work in my case

Tags: javascript, tom-select

I have in my `file.json`:

```
[
    {
        "url":"http://link.one",
        "title":"One title"
    },
    {
        "url":"http://link.two",
        "title":"Two title"
    },
    {
        "url":"http://link.three",
        "title":"Three title"
    },
    ...
]
```

I added to HTML:
`<select name="json" id="json" aria-label="Select item" placeholder="Enter text...">`

I took the example from [here...](https://tom-select.js.org/examples/remote/)

In my JS:

```
var settings = {
    create: false,
    maxOptions: 10,
    maxItems: 1,

    valueField: 'url',
    labelField: 'title',
    searchField: 'title',
    sortField: 'title',

    load: function(query, callback) {

        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/data/file.json?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                callback(json.items);
            }).catch(()=>{
                callback();
            });

    },

    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return `<div class="py-2 d-flex">
                        <a href="${item.url}">${ escape(item.title) }</a>
                    </div>`;
        },

        item: function(item, escape) {
            return `<div class="py-2 d-flex">
                        <a href="${item.url}">${ escape(item.title) }</a>
                    </div>`;
        }
    },

    onChange: function(value) {
        if (value !== '') {
            window.location = value;
        }
    }
};
new TomSelect('#json', settings);
```

..., but all of this do not work, I always get "No results found". Why and what is wrong with my code? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to make sure you're getting the expected JSON response.

Comment: If you're using a static JSON file, the the `q=` parameter isn't going to do anything.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I tried but it does not working. Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `items` property in your JSON file. It should be something like:

```
{
  "items": [{
      "url": "http://link.one",
      "title": "One title"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://link.two",
      "title": "Two title"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://link.three",
      "title": "Three title"
    }
  ]
}
```

or change the JavaScript to:

```
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(items => {
                callback(items);
            }).catch(()=>{
                callback();
            });
```

Comment: thanks! How about that VAR...
`var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/data/file.json...`
What need tot do here...?

Comment: That doesn't change. I think the `q=...` part will be ignored, it's only meaningful when you call an API.